# Can't read json_encode

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm having an issue. I have a json_encode array in php. With ajax, I get back in my javascript script.

**php**

```
<?php
$code = 'xyz';
$email = 'xyz@gmail.com';
$back = array();
array_push($back, array("code" => $code,"email" => $email));
echo json_encode($back);
?>
```

**ajax callback function**

```
function(data){
alert(data);
alert(data[0].code);
}
```

When I try to alert data, I get `[{"code":"xyz","email":"xyz@gmail.com"}]`

Now when I try to alert the code (or the email) it says `undefined`.

Can you help me alert data[0].code properly ?

Comment: Your response probably isn't being parsed as JSON. Set `dataType: "json"` in your ajax call. Or update your question showing your full ajax code if that doesn't work.

Comment: Also, why even nest that array in the first place? It would simplify thing if you just did `$back = ["code" => $code,"email" => $email];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your ajax options set `dataType: "JSON"`

Comment: my fault. my fault

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse it

```
function(data){
    var obj = JSON.parse(data[0]);
    alert(obj.code)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

its working ,i am tried in jsfiddle

```
var data=[{"code":"xyz","email":"xyz@gmail.com"}]
alert(data);
alert(data[0].code);
```

i got in alert xyz